# filter vector (read most recent filename)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am reading out all the files in a directory using `list.files()`.
Then, I need to extract the most recent filename "myfileX.sav" (in the example below this should be myfile11.sav).

```r
#files <- list.files(here::here(), full.names = T)

# Some example filenames:
files <- c("xyz.sav", paste0("myfile", 1:11, ".sav"), "anotherone.sav")
```

What's the most elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `file.info` function over files and then look at `mtime` and `ctime` to find out what file is the most recent.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not use meta data of the files but the filenames instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
#Select the filenames that have myfile in it
myfiles <- grep('myfile', files, value = TRUE)
#Remove all non-numeric data from file name convert to number 
#and get the filename corresponding to max value
myfiles[which.max(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', myfiles)))]
#[1] "myfile11.sav"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
myfiles <- grep('^myfile', basename(files), value = TRUE)
myfiles[order(-readr::parse_number(myfiles)][1]
```